# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/signup/ django-allauth error

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have this code in my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^profile/', include('userProfile.urls')),
]
```

and this is the userProfile.urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    profile_user,
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/profile/$', profile_user),
]
```

And I get this error NoReverseMatch at /accounts/signup. I read somewhere that the problem must be in the urls.py file, but I don't know why, if someone can help, it would be nice. Everything worked fine last time I checked, and now something went wrong. Thank you.

I understand that the error might not be clear enough, so i copied the whole error from browser:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.11
Python Path:    
['D:\\Programiranje\\Python\\Projekat ISA\\ProjekatRestorani',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 19 May 2016 12:03:20 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\allauth\templates\account\login.html, error at line 14
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
4   {% load account socialaccount %}
5   
6   {% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}
7   
8   {% block content %}
9   
10  <h1>{% trans "Sign In" %}</h1>
11  
12  {% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
13  
14  {% if socialaccount_providers %}
15  <p>{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
16  of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
17  for a {{ site_name }} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}</p>
18  
19  <div class="socialaccount_ballot">
20  
21    <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
22      {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
23    </ul>
```

But that is not my login.html code... This is what I have in my login.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

<p>{% trans "Forgot password" %}? <a href="{% url 'auth_password_reset' %}">{% trans "Reset it" %}</a>!</p>
<p>{% trans "Not member" %}? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

So if I delete the files from my templates folder, and let him be empty, it works fine. I hope I gave you some useful information now.

Comment: need to see `allauth.urls` module

Comment: When does the error appear, is there a stacktrace?

Comment: are you using allauth or not? if yes why in your template there is no allauth code like you had been using it without it
are you sure that your login.htmk is in "account" subdirectory of templates dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in your HTML. Try to namespace that url by adding name='profile'. Check in your HTML if you have something like

```
href="{% url 'YourApp:profile' %}"
```

You should check if your url's do have a ReverseMatch.